An object won't move
Tested in Blender 4.0 to 4.2.
Object mode
Trying to move a door object and I can't. I can rotate and scale though.
Any other object would move normally in that model.
Checked:

transforms scale applied
no modifiers or constraints
no affect origins
selectable
origin near geometry
geometry at world origin
snaps off
no scene drivers or weird custom properties
no parenting or specific hierarchies.

Also, there is no move gizmo for the door, but rotate and scale gizmos can be shown.
Really, I think I stripped the file with anything that could potentially interfere.
This is part of a collection I downloaded from BlenderKit and copied to an empty blend.
Nothing like this has happened before.
How to live?
The file:


The Location and X and Y Rotation of your object are locked as you can see from the marked closed padlocks. Click on each padlock or drag the mouse down over all of them with the left button down to unlock them and you'll be able to move the door. You can leave the rotation ones locked as the door should only rotate on the Z axis.


Thank you. I am again ashamed for missing such a basic thing.

No problem! :^)
